# Consecutive Strings

Tags: c, string

**Task:**
You are given an array `strarr` of strings and an integer `k`. Your task is to return the first longest string consisting of `k` consecutive strings taken in the array.

**Example**:

```
longest_consec(["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail"], 2) --> "abigailtheta"
```

**Note:**
Consecutive strings follow one after another without an interruption,

Final code(working):

```
char *longestConsec(char *strarr[], int n, int k) {
    if (n == 0 || k > n || k <= 0)
        return "";

    int max_len = 0, len, max_length_returned = 0;
    for (int l = 0; l < n; ++l) {
        max_length_returned += (int)strlen(strarr[l]);
    }
    char *max_str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * max_length_returned + 1); // problem was here - not freed (because need to return it)
    char *str_temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * max_length_returned + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n - k + 1; ++i) {
        strcpy(str_temp, strarr[i]);
        for (int j = 1; j < k; ++j) {
            strcat(str_temp, strarr[i + j]);
        }
        len = (int)strlen(str_temp);
        if (max_len < len) {
            max_len = len;
            strcpy(max_str, str_temp);
        }
    }
    free(str_temp);
    return max_str;
}

int main() {
    char *a[] = { "zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail" };
    char *longest = longestConsec(a, 8, 2);
    printf("string: %s\nlength: %d\n", longest, (int)strlen(longest));
    free(longest);
    return 0;
}
```

My code works fine but I have a memory leak. Any ideas how to solve the above problem?

Edit: A better-looking solution I found using indexes(`start` & `nd`) for anyone who's interested

```
char *longestConsec(char *strarr[], int n, int k) {
    if ((n == 0) || (k > (int)n) || (k <= 0))
        return "";
    int maxSum = 0, start = 0, nd = 0; // creating indexes
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - k; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < i + k; j++)
            sum += (int)strlen(strarr[j]);
        if (sum > maxSum) {
            maxSum = sum; start = i; nd = i + k;
        }
    }
    char *longest = malloc(sizeof(char) * maxSum + 1); // have the exact amount to allocate
    longest[0] = '\0'; // The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source
    for (int c = start; c < nd; c++)
        strcat(longest, strarr[c]);
    return longest;
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us more context. Can the function parameters be changed? Can the caller free the string? What are the problem constraints? The usual approaches are for the caller to free or caller to pass in a buffer.

Comment: The code that calls `longestConsec` needs to free the memory. [Edit] your question and show us that code. Read this: [ask] and this : [mcve]

Comment: Also, `sizeof(strarr)` is wrong. That will give the size of a single pointer and not the size of the array. The array size cannot be calculated from a pointer. I assume `n` is the number of elements in the array so you need `malloc(n*sizeof(char *)`

Comment: Yeah the parameters can be changed. The caller is the main function but it cannot free it there. I think the task demands from me to change the strarr paramaters and I tried to change strarr[i] each iteration with strcat() but the problem there is the dest string isn't long enough to contain both. that's why I created max_str and allocated memory for it

Comment: @kaylum I don't need the number of elements in the array but the number of chars in total so I can allocate the max amount of memory needed for the worst case

Comment: @BarBenjamin please read the second comment and comply. _"The caller is the main function but it cannot free it there"_: why? Show your code instead of describing it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Updated. because the task prohibits that. ofc I can just free it in the main and pass max_str to the function but it's not allowed here

Comment: @BarBenjamin _"because the task prohibits that."_ what? You need to be more explicit, for example by showing us what the task is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays in the two calls to `malloc(sizeof(strarr))`. The variable *strarr* is a pointer to a string, not the string itself which has not been allocated. The size of *strarr* is just sufficient to contain one address, or few characters, but normally not an entire string. So you are using a random part of the memory for storing the end of your string.

If you maintain your code more or less as it is, you will need to know how long the resulting longest string will be for allocating it with `malloc(sizeof(char) * max_length_returned)`.

Comment: That's correct, but that's not what the OP was asking about.

Comment: Merci beaucoup Pierre, it actually worked but I still don't understand how it overcame the memory leak I had - I didn't free it still. (code is updated)

Comment: Also mention that `return "";` is incorrect as the caller cannot determine whether to free the object or not. `return strdup("");` is required.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in `main` is still not completely correct. You are calling `longestConsec` twice and you never free the memory returned.

You need to free the memory returned by `longestConsec`:

```
int main()
{
  char* a[] = { "zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas", "theta", "abigail" };

  char* longest = longestConsec(a, 8, 2);  // call longestConsec only once
  printf("string: %s\nlength: %d\n", longest, (int)strlen(longest));
  free(longest);

  return 0;
}
```

Generally spoken: anything that has been returned by `malloc` and friends must be freed by a call to `free` at some point.

**Disclaimer:** I didn't check if there are more bugs in `longestConsec`.

Comment: I tried to V both of you but it doesn't seem to be possible. I gave pierre because he has less points. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: _"it doesn't seem to be possible"_: why? What happended? Did it set your your computer  on fire?

Comment: @BarBenjamin lol _"is doesn't let me"_: who or what is _"it"_?

Comment: You can V only *one* answer

Comment: _"You can V only one answer"_: still not quite understanding what is _V_ ???

Comment: Anyway independently of the fact that someone or something won't let you do whatever: your code in `main` is wrong.

Comment: @BarBenjamin OK, now I've got you. Never mind for the points, the most important is you've understood the problems in your code. Actually both answers deal with a different problem in your code.